# Reuse Django Rest Framework Generic view to get its QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Generic View of Django Rest Framework with a lot of settings (sorting, filtering, searching, etc):

```py
class MyViewClass(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ...  # IMPORTANT: this uses self.request

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return ...  # IMPORTANT: this uses self.request

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filter_backends = [CustomOrdering, filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['field1', 'field2']
    ordering_fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
```

Now I want to make a file download from a QuerySet which **must be computed with the same filters, sorting and searching parameters**. Is there a way to reuse the QuerySet computed by that view? I **don't need that to be paginated** (however I think I could solve that problem from the frontend, so It doesn't worry me).

I've tried calling `get_queryset` method with an ugly trick but It's not applying searching and ordering:

```py
@login_required()
def download_result_with_filters(request):
    class MockRequest:
        request: HttpRequest
    mock_request = MockRequest()
    mock_request.request = request
    queryset = MyView.get_queryset(mock_request)
    ...
```

Any kind of help would be really appreciated

Comment: you probably are looking for renderers https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've found a solution getting the data from the view response. I'll submit an answer later!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to call the `MyViewClass` inside `download_result_with_filters`:

```py
@login_required()
def download_result_with_filters(request):
    comb_dict: List[OrderedDict] = MyViewClass.as_view()(request=request).data['results']
```

In `data` you can get all the response of the Django REST Framework view, like pagination fields. In the example above I just needed the elements of the resulting QuerySet, which is contained in the `results` field from the paginated response